# how to change to foo.sharepoint.com/default.aspx instead of foo.sharepoint.com/Pages/default.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, url

I use the trial online 365 sharepoint and just get a team website. The home web page is located as far as /Pages/default.aspx and i wonder if there is a way to sorten that /Pages/ part? i want people could type shortly mysite.sharepoint.com and access directly to web pages instead of long default url bla-bla-bla/**Pages**/default.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint designer to create pages at the root instead of inside the Pages library, but I wouldn't recommend it as it's a lot more work.

But your users don't have to specify the `/Pages/default.aspx` part. They can just write `http://mysite.sharepoint.com` and that'll bring them to `http://mysite.sharepoint.com/Pages/default.aspx`

Comment: Ok, in fact they don't need to type you are right. As for use of designer capabilities i use online sharepoint so i don't have this choice. If nobody give me exact answer i will count your as answer to my question

Comment: You should still be able to use SharePoint designer even though you're on SharePoint Online, unless it has been prohibited by your organisation